# SSH key not working for git push unless recently logged in

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

### Background

I use SiteGround to host my websites.  I have git repos set up for each of my sites on SiteGround.  I use SSH keys for authentication.  I just set siteground to be one of my remotes that I can push too.

### The problem

The SSH keys appear to expire after a while, unless I login via SSH.  I haven't been able to determine how long it takes before expiration.  It seems to be a few weeks.

### Procedure

1. Wait a few weeks.
2. Make some modifications to my website, commit and merge to `main`.
3. `$ git push sitegroundRemote HEAD:master`

Then I get this error:

```
$ git push sitegroundRemote HEAD:master
<username>@subdomain.siteground.biz: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

4. `$ ssh sitename`   <-- this works.  I'm now logged into a remote session
5. `$ exit`
6. `$ git push sitegroundRemote HEAD:master`

And now it works.  And I can continue to push for the next few days or weeks without having to `ssh` in.

It seems like the key expires for git purposes, but not logging into the shell.  And logging into the shell re-enables the key to be used for git purposes.

### Additional Info

#### SSH config

The entry in my ~/.ssh/config file looks like:

```
Host sitename
  HostName sitename.com
  User <user-name>
  Port <port-number>
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/sitename.com
```

#### git config

The entry in my git config file looks like:

```
[remote "sitegroundRemote"]
    url = ssh://<user-name>@<subdomain>.siteground.biz:<port>/home/<user-name>/www/sitename.com/repos/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/master/*
```

#### Generating the SSH key

To generate my SSH key, I did the following:

1. `$ ssh-keygen`
2. Entered location and name and password (`/Users/username/.ssh/sitename.com`)
3. `$ ssh-add -K /Users/username/.ssh/sitename.com`
4. `$ pbcopy < ~/.ssh/sitename.com.pub`
5. Paste that into SiteGround's SSH key section.

All of this allows me to just `$ ssh sitename` to gain access to my site via bash.  So the key works.  I didn't use any `-t` options to put a time limit on it or anything.

### The question

Any idea how I can continue to push to SiteGround without having to login every so often?

I should add that I did contact SiteGround's support, and the answer was basically "Sessions expire. There's nothing we can do about it."  So I'm hoping someone here has some ideas.

Comment: Are you using an ssh agent? Do you add ssh keys with a particular lifetime, using `ssh-add -t`? See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122511/162084).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I'm hoping someone here has some ideas.

Beside a workaround, there might not be any obvious solution.

As a workaround, you could set a cron job which, every day, would do a `ssh sitename ls` (single command and exit), in order to "refresh" the session.